# what is regex doing in the background?

Tags: regex

I played around with regex today and I stepped on something I don't really understand why it behave like this.

This is my working regex (I formatted it for better readability):

```
(?<name>[a-z\ ]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+)\ 
(?<firstname>[a-z-A-Z\ ]+)\n
(?<title>[a-zA-Z\.\ ]+)\n?
(?<company>[a-zA-Zäöü\.\ ]+)?\n
(?<street>[a-zA-Zäöü]+)\ (?<housenumber>[0-9]+)\n?
(?<postfach>Postfach [0-9]+)?\n
(?<zip>[0-9]+)\ (?<place>[a-zA-Zäöü]+)
```

And this is the string I want to parse through:

```
Smith John
Dr.
Foobar AG
Smithstrasse 1
Postfach 1
6500 Bellinzona
```

With this regex it'll work perfectly. But previously the `\n` before group `street` was nullable and not the `\n` before group `company`. The thing is that there's a case where the string has no company in it. The result with the previous version: The whole street exept for the last char was in the group `company` and the last char of the street in group `street` (I used regex101 for testing). Although group `company` is nullable it looks like it "forced" to be part of the string which is definetly not the thing I want.

And that's where my quesion comes. How does regex work exactly in the background? I think regex is trying to take the best solution out of all the possible groupings it can have in the string. But I have no clue why it takes this solution as the best one.

Here's a link to regex101 where you can see how it behaved previously: https://regex101.com/r/OmuPBn/1

Comment: You can turn on the debugger in regex 101 to see what steps it exactly takes to get the matches. In this case regex matches greedy, thus tries to match as much as possible from left to right and then tracks back character for character if it has to in order to get a match.

Comment: @SebastianProske thanks for tip. I didn't know regex101 has a debugger.

Comment: Side note : you're escaping too much in your character classes. Only `]`, and `-` when in the middle of the class, have a special meaning in this context and need to be escaped if you want to refer to their literal characters. Same for the space which is last character of the first line : no need to escape it, it has no special meaning and will be matched literally by default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How a RegEx engine works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622398/how-a-regex-engine-works)