# Why regex group doesn't work

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I've tried the following regx (java string format):

```
^(.*(iOS\\s+[\\d\\.]+|Android\\s+[\\d\\.]+)?.*)$
```

String to match is :

```
Some Money 2.6.2; iOS 5.1.1
```

It supposes to return three groups :

```
group[0] :Some Money 2.6.2; iOS 5.1.1
group[1] :Some Money 2.6.2; iOS 5.1.1
group[2] :iOS 5.1.1
```

but it actually returns these:

```
group[0] :Some Money 2.6.2; iOS 5.1.1 
group[1] :Some Money 2.6.2; iOS 5.1.1 
group[2] :null
```

when i change regex as below

```
^(.*(iOS\\s+[\\d\\.]+|Android\\s+[\\d\\.]+).*)$
```

but it can't match string like

```
whatever iS 5.1.1 whatever
```

What i want to achieve is the regex returns three groups no matter what string likes.The first and second group always to be the entire string . The third group is the substring that matches '(iOS|Android) [\d.]*' if string does contains that part and is null or empty if it doesn't contain.

Comment: It doesn't match the second group, because it is optional and `.*` has already consumed the whole string.

Comment: I tried solving a problem with regex. Now I have two problems.

Comment: You can use [`^(.*((?:iOS|Android)\s+[\d.]+).*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/OLlDoN/1)

Comment: When everything is optional in the regex, something is wrong with the approach. Look, you could use [`^((?:(?!(?:iOS|Android)\s+[\d.]).)*((?:iOS|Android)\s+[\d.]+)?.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/z14jt9/1), but do you really want to? I suggest checking for just `(?:iOS|Android)\s+[\d.]+` pattern and if not, take the whole string, else grab the string and the match.

Comment: Then how can i change the regex to avoid these,since string before "iOS " has no fixed pattern. @SebastianProske

Comment: I can't use it ,since when the string  has no substring matches  (iOS|Android)\s[\d.]+ ,for example "Some Money 2.6.2; iS 5.1.1 ", three groups was expected to be returned, but it actually returns none. @anubhava

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the `;` delimiter as indication that your `iOS 5.1.1` part starts?

Then a pattern may look like `.+;\\s+(.+)`.

- `.+;` consumes everything up to the semi-colon
- `\\s+` consumes the spaces between semi-colon and the start of the version string
- `(.+)` consumes everything up to the end

If you really only want to match *iOS* or *Android* then you might want to add a non capturing group within the `(.+)` part.
A regexp then would look like this: `".+;\\s+((?:iOS|Android).+)"`.

And here a executable example what a solution may look like. It shows the behaviour of both pattern variants I explained above.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input1 = "Some Money 2.6.2; iS 5.1.1 ";
    String input2 = "Some Money 2.6.2; iOS 5.1.1 ";
    String input3 = "Some Money 2.6.2; Android 5.1.1 ";

    String pattern1 = ".+;\\s+(.+)";
    String pattern2 = ".+;\\s+((?:iOS|Android).+)";

    System.out.println(pattern1);
    matchPattern(input1, pattern1);
    matchPattern(input2, pattern1);
    matchPattern(input3, pattern1);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(pattern2);
    matchPattern(input1, pattern2);
    matchPattern(input2, pattern2);
    matchPattern(input3, pattern2);
}

private static void matchPattern(String input, String pattern) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if(m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        if(m.groupCount() > 1) {
            System.out.println(m.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** Since the target of the question got clearer due to some edits by the author, I feel the need to update my answer. If it is about always getting three groups, the following might be better than working out all possible notation variants:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input1 = "Some Money 2.6.2; iS 5.1.1";
    String input2 = "Some Money 2.6.2; iOS 5.1.1";
    String input3 = "Some Money 2.6.2; Android 5.1.1";
    String input4 = "Some Money 2.6.2 iOS 5.1.1";
    String input5 = "Some Money 2.6.2 iOS";
    String input6 = "Some Money 2.6.2";

    String pattern1 = "(.*?((?:iOS|Android)(?:\\s+[0-9\\.]+)?.*)?)";

    System.out.println(pattern1);
    matchPattern(input1, pattern1);
    matchPattern(input2, pattern1);
    matchPattern(input3, pattern1);
    matchPattern(input4, pattern1);
    matchPattern(input5, pattern1);
    matchPattern(input6, pattern1);
}

private static void matchPattern(String input, String pattern) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    if(m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(0));
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Here the pattern is `(.*?(?:((?:iOS|Android)(?:\\s+[0-9\\.]+)?).*)?)`.

- `.*?` consumes everything before the version string. If no version string is available at all it matches the whole input. *The [Reluctant quantifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) is needed here. It takes the shortest match that still matches and so avoids that the whole input is consumed.*
- `(?:((?:iOS|Android)(?:\\s+[0-9\\.]+)?).*)?` consumes the whole version string and everything that is following.
- `((?:iOS|Android)(?:\\s+[0-9\\.]+)?)` is the *group(2)* output. It just matches the OS string, *iOS* or *Android*, with an optional version suffix consisting of numbers and dot.

Comment: [It does not seem to work](https://regex101.com/r/3CCnG8/1) for string 2.

Comment: Of cause not, because the regexp is explicitly limited to *iOS* and *Android*. I explained the more general approach in my answer while the code uses the more specific one only matching *iOS* and *Android*.

Comment: Then you just need to add the logic to return the expected results. Moreover, the unanchored regex would be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But actually i can't ensure string's format, it may contains no  character ';' . What i want to achieve is that the regex return three groups no matter what the string like.

Answer (score 0):

please refer [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622398/how-a-regex-engine-works) about "How a RegEx engine works".

> 2. *Those based on back-tracking*. These often compile the pattern into byte-code, resembling machine instructions. The engine then executes the code, jumping from instruction to instruction. When an instruction fails, it then back-tracks to find another way to match the input.

Your regular expression have many way to match the input. And sadly, it return the other way (not your expected matches).

By removing "?" quantifier from the 2nd group, it becomes "required".
Your returned maches will match all required groups.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem by regex as below.

```
(.*((?:iOS|Android)\\s+[0-9\\.]+).*|.*)
```