# Why are Java regular expressions compiled?

Tags: java, regex, string, performance, compilation

I understand that Java regular expressions need to be compiled in order to do any type of regular expression pattern matching on strings, but I don't understand *why* they need to be compiled.

What the is the more efficient representation that a regex string is compiled to? And how is that representation more efficient than a String?

Comment: A kind of optimal parsing grammar is derived. As patterns can be repeated thousand times, say on lines of text files, this seems worth the effort. Still regex can be slow because of backtracking and such. This is typical of declarative programming: you tell what you want, but the procedure you leave that to the implementation

Comment: The regex engine doesn't use strings, the *pattern* just gives it the instructions for what it searches, virtually all engines will turn that pattern in a different representation. Usually a state machine

Comment: @JoopEggen That makes sense, but what is that optimal parsing grammar and how is it more efficient than representing the regex as a string?

Comment: @VLAZ What is that different representation though? And how is it more efficient than a vanilla String?

Comment: Doing regex oneself is not difficult, so implement a straight forward solution for `.*+?|()` and do some timings.

Comment: BTW of course it is not a real "compile." If you dive into the sources of Pattern.compile you'll find peep hold optimization, temporary storage and such.

Comment: If you construct a state machine that defines the transitions through consuming characters, then you simplify your process of matching immensely `/\d\s_/` turns into into states and transitions and you start consuming characters: "1 _"` -> grab "1" -> good, matches `\d` -> move to next state -> grab " " -> good, matches `\s` -> move to next state -> grab "_" -> good, matches `_` -> done. And if you supply "1a_" ->  grab "1" -> good, matches `\d` -> move to next state -> grab "a" -> doesn't match `\s` -> end

Comment: @VLAZ I think this is the answer I'm looking for. I still don't know much about state machines, but it sounds like that is the more efficient representation of a regex when compared to a string representation. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, Regular Expression *engines* use a set of instructions to know how to walk through the target text and match portions of it. The high level (human-readable) pattern that we as developers write is like your source code in Java (or really any other language). The computer does not *run* your source code, it compiles that into instructions the computer can understand. Similarly, your RegEx pattern is compiled into a set of instructions that the RegEx engine (regardless of programming language) can process.

I personally find the [Regular-Expressions.info site very helpful](https://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html) for lots of explanations, although their explanation of how the engine works internally is a bit light. This [answer on SO is decent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3626566/1985406), with some other links.

If you want a more in depth answer, I would look at [this page](http://wstoop.co.za/wregex.php) which talks about the nature of Regular Expression engines, which is that they are **finite state machines**.

> Regular expression engines are implemented as finite state machines (FSM). The pattern you supply is compiled into a data structure that represents this state machine.
>
> When you match a string against this pattern, the regex engine takes each character and decides the state transition within the FSM. If there are no valid state transitions for an input character the match fails.
>
> One of the states in the FSM is a terminating/end state. If the regex engine gets there it reports success.

To answer your "how is that more efficient than a string" question, it can't be a string... you have to get the low-level instructions for the engine. A String type isn't a set of instructions!

Comment: This is super helpful! I still don't feel like I 100% know the answer to this question, but this definitely moves me a lot closer. And part of the reason I may not be 100% there yet, is that I don't know much at all about finite state machines. So, your provided links will be very valuable. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> What the is the more efficient representation that a regex string is compiled to? And how is that representation more efficient than a String?

Your question doesn't make much sense; I'm assuming you're asking about "compiled" vs "translated" RegEx which are basically the same thing anyway.

RegEx is essentially just a language for describing (to a computer) what you want to match.

Think of the RegEx string like code, the computer can't do anything with it until it's translated to something it can use first.

So "compiling" RegEx is just translating that string into machine instructions.

It is "more efficient than a String" because when you store the `Pattern` then you keep those instructions for matching to be re-used efficiently without having to re-translate the same RegEx string.

Eg. the below is (as I understand it) what you mean by compiled vs string representation:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // using "string representation"
    System.out.println("some string".matches("myRegex"));


    // using "compiled representation"
    Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("myRegex");

    Matcher myMatcher1 = myPattern.matcher("some string 1");
    Matcher myMatcher2 = myPattern.matcher("some string 2");

    System.out.println(myMatcher1.matches());
    System.out.println(myMatcher2.matches());
}
```

But if you look at the method used by `"some string".matches("myRegex")` then you'll see that it also calls `Pattern.compile()` to translate the RegEx instructions:

**String.java**

```
public boolean matches(String regex) {
    // return Pattern.matches(regex, this);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
    return m.matches();
}
```

So using the "string representation" still compiles the RegEx, it just doesn't cache the pattern for re-use.

Comment: I understand that much. You say, "the computer can't do anything with it until it's translated to something it can use first." My question is what is the RegEx translated to? Some of the answers above mentioned that the RegEx is translated to a finite state machine. And that's what I was looking for with this question.